# How to Instantiate and Mock Objects with Arguments in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

For the past couple of days I have been in annotation/mocking hell. I have been running into the following issue:

```
Failed to instantiate [com.test.service.util.Utils]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: value1 cannot be null
```

I am writing mocked tests for a Service class which has a Utils class inside of it. This Utils class relies on a values in the Spring application properties file. It seems to me that the @Value members are being injected as null. How do I instantiate an object with arguments and mock it in Spring?

Service.java looks like this:

```
@Service
public class Service {

  @Value("${value1}")
  private String value1;

  private Utils utils = new Utils(value1);

  public service_method1() {
     utils.utils_method1();
  }
}
```

The Utils class looks like this:

```
@Component
public class Utils {

private OtherUtils otherUtils;

public Utils(String value1) {
    otherUtils = new OtherUtils(value1);
}

public utils_method1() {
    otherUtils.otherUtils_method1()
}

}
```

ServiceTests.java looks like this:

```
public class ServiceTests {

private String VALUE1 = "value1";

@Mock
private Utils utils = new Utils(value1);

@InjectMocks
private Service service;

@Test test_method1() {
   //set up mocks for Utils methods
   //run Service class methods
}

}
```

Comment: Try using `@Spy` instead of `@Mock` for the `utils` member variable in your test.

Comment: Cheers for the fast response, still no dice though. I removed all @Autowire annotations, are those needed anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create an object of `Utils` in `Service` instead you can `autowire` it, so replace 
 `private Utils utils = new Utils(value1);` with

```
@Autowire
private Utils utils;
```

If you want the `value1` in `Utils` then move

```
 @Value("${value1}")
 private String value1;
```

to `Utils`.

finally to set the private properties use `ReflectionTestUtils` from spring `ReflectionTestUtils.setField(targetObject, name, value);`

Comment: Hello Jobin, thanks for your response. I am trying out what you outlined, where do I use ReflectionTestUtils.setField(targetObject, name, value); in what class/method? Thanks

Comment: In the test class